# Random Tiled Map Libgdx Java

Tags: java, libgdx, tile

I am trying to create a game that is top down 2d and using a pixel tiled map style format, similar to a top down minecraft. The way i would like to do it is have 4 different tiles, different shades of green and brown for grass. I would like to generate these 4 tiles randomly around the 1920*1080 pixel area to give a semi realistic effect.

I am struggling to find information about using TiledMap online, and although i think is the way to go i am struggling.

**Ideas:**

Randomly select the tiles, assigning them a numerical value, picking a random number and using a case statement to select the relevant tile, then put them in order in an array **(not sure how this would be done)**. Then render them each using Tiled Map. Any ideas???

**Simple exlanations would be much appreciated**

Comment: Don't use a tiled map, just use a 2D array.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Ok can u use that to render them then? Any examples?

Comment: Iterate through the tiles and draw them.

Comment: @AnubianNoob OK any code or example pls as i am new to Java and Libgdx

Comment: As found by @KrackLocks a possible answer for the question can be found here [How would I implement procedurally generated tiles in libgdx?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/67992/34281)